# Getting http post response in JavaScriptCore for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to play around with `JavaScriptCore.framework` and I'm trying to make an http post request but I'm not getting a response at all.

My code:

Objective C:

```
#define UTILITY_PATH        ([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GeneralUtility" ofType:@"js"])
#define WEB_SERVICE_PATH    ([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WebService" ofType:@"js"])

- (void)testJavaScript
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
    NSString *scriptString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:WEB_SERVICE_PATH encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%s, error: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error.localizedDescription);
    }

    [context evaluateScript:scriptString];

    context[@"print"] = ^(NSString *text) {
        NSLog(@"text: %@", text);
    };

    JSValue *function = context[@"getGoogleLocationResponse"];
    [function callWithArguments:@[]];
}
```

And JavaScript:

```
function getGoogleLocationResponse()
{
    var lat = "31.1", lon = "34.4";
    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lon"+&sensor=false";

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET", url, false);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    request.send(null);

    print("response text: "+request.responseText);
}
```

As I read about `XLHttpRequest` I didn't see anything about not supporting safari browser.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[JSContext alloc] init] creates a standalone webkit-free JavaScript Context instance. That means that only the JavaScript Virtual Machine Core is available by default: no DOM, no setInterval, no XMLHttpRequest, etc.

If you want to use XMLHttpRequest you have to create your custom binding or get the JSContext instance from a UIWebView.